# System dialog Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, button, angular-material, angular-material2

I work for system of dialog (Angular Material).

I create dialog-service for controll and container dialog. Dialog-service has methods for open/show different dialoges.

And I create dialog-component for contain data for dialog (it is single component of dialog). It is universal component.

I add [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-ah8bcs)

I have problem with closing dialoges after callback.
How I can close dialog after callback? I try using **[mat-dialog-close]** - but I was not able to somehow parameterize - enable and disable the **[mat-dialog-close]** of different buttons.

And a have little problem. How I can add dynamicly **mat-button** to button element?

(I add class 'mat-button', but this don't full imitation mat-button)

```
 <div *ngIf="getButtons().length > 0 || getCloseButton()" mat-dialog-actions>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let button of getButtons()">
      <button [attr.class]="button.class"
        (click)="button.callback(button.callbackItem || dialogForm)">{{button.title}}</button>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your dialog.html you must have something like this:

```
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="closeDialog()">Close</button>
```

and in your dialog.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.scss']
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Yep, this good idea, but I think HOW relation between dialog-service and dialog-component. How I formation button data for dialog-component that somethink buttons close dialog after callback function? Please, look at StackBlitz example.